# firebase callable functions returning CORS error and not being called from client

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been using firebase functions for quite some time and all deployments of functions have been going quite smoothly. All of a sudden any new functions deployed have stopped working and any calls from the client return a CORS error. If I check the functions list in the firebase dashboard I can't see the functions being called which is similar to what I would expect if the functions simply didn't exist at all.

I am now just trying a simple basic function like below:

```
exports.createSession = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return ({status: 200})
});
```

On the frontend I am doing a simple call like below:

```
const createSessionFunction = functions.httpsCallable('createSession');
const response = await createSessionFunction({});
```

All the other functions that were create and deployed prior to this week are working fine. Any new functions are not.

The error I get is below:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://europe-west2-xxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/createSession' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
index.cjs.js:614 POST https://europe-west2-xxxxxxxz.cloudfunctions.net/createSession net::ERR_FAILED
```

My function list on the firebase GUI show this function does exist:

```
createSession - Request - https://europe-west2-xxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/createSession-europe-west2-Node.js 8 -256 MB - 60s
```

However the logs show that it is never called from the client when I'm trying to test it which means the client might not be detecting this function at all.

I have tried the following steps with no luck:

1. Delete and redeploy the functions
2. Rename the function and redeploy
3. Deploy the same new function on different applications (dev/test etc)

Any ideas?

Comment: When did you deployed this functions? as some permissions changed early this year on newly deployed function.  Also what status code is the preflight fetch passing to your apllication?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved on the google cloud dashboard by granting all my functions public access. The default permissions has changed from public to private.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation